# How can I add side and upper border of menu option in CSPageMenuOption in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to make menu option similar to given design but unable to add side and top boarder because there is not attribute or I haven't seen any attribute of the CAPSPageMenuOption(third party library). Also there is an attribute to change color of label of selected item but how can selected item background can be changed. I have got suggestion to remove bottomhairline attribute. and and add simple boarders but still I unable to get it. I don't have much experience, I am struck in here for quite a while, so If any one can help, please..

What I have done is:

```
        let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
           //.selectionIndicatorColor(UIColor.red), ////// Indicator
            .scrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor.white),
            .menuItemSeparatorWidth(1),
            .menuItemSeparatorColor(UIColor.red),
            .useMenuLikeSegmentedControl(true),
            .menuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight(1.0),
            .bottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor.red), // line
            .menuHeight(50.0),
            .menuItemFont(UIFont(name: Constants.kFONT_BOLD, size: 
             15)!),
            .viewBackgroundColor(UIColor.red),
            .selectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.gray),
            .unselectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.red),
            .addBottomMenuHairline(true),
            .centerMenuItems(true)]

              pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, 
                frame: CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 
                 self.containerView.frame.width, height: 
               self.containerView.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: 
               parameters)

          // Lastly add page menu as subview of base view controller view
          // or use pageMenu controller in you view hierachy as desired
            self.containerView.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
```

I want output like this:
[image: The output I want]

But I am getting this [image: The output I am getting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to eidt some code inside CAPSPageMenu files. In CAPSPageMenu.swift, there is function moveSelectionIndicator(_pageIndex: Int), inside it add this code

```
`        self.menuItems[self.lastPageIndex].backgroundColor = UIColor.white
         self.menuItems[self.currentPageIndex].backgroundColor = 
                   UIColor.red
         self.menuItems[self.lastPageIndex].backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                `
```

This will make changing color things work..

Answer (score 1):

Do below changed in CAPSPageMenu.m file

Add the below code in the method
- (void)moveSelectionIndicator:(NSInteger)pageIndex

```
                MenuItemView *lastview = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:self.lastPageIndex];
                [lastview.layer setBorderWidth:0.0];

                MenuItemView *currentView = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:self.currentPageIndex];
                [currentView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
                [currentView.layer setBorderColor:self.borderColor.CGColor];
```

In initWithViewControllers method add below code at the end (This is for initially selected menu)

```
             MenuItemView *currentView = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:self.currentPageIndex];
            [currentView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
            [currentView.layer setBorderColor:self.borderColor.CGColor];
```